# Browser Not Rendering The View File In Grails Webflows

Tags: grails, groovy

I created a new controller named `ShopController`, to use in Webflows. This is the code :

```
class ShopController {

    def index() { 
        redirect(action:"order")
    }
   def orderFlow = {
    display {
        on("next") {
        }.to("finish")
    }
    finish { 
    redirect(controller:"user", action:"index")
    }
   }
}
```

And in `views/shop/order/display` I created a file like this :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>  
    </head>
<body>

<h1>Testing</h1>
 Testing webflows.
 <g:form action="order">
 </g:form>

</body>
</html>
```

However upto this it looks simple, when I run my grails app and pointing the browser to `http://localhost:8080/testing/shop/order/display` I'm getting nothing. Nothing in sense, there is no error message from Apache, no text, I'm seeing only a blank screen.

I'm using Grails 2.0

Where did I go wrong? Did I make any silly mistakes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found where I was making a mistake.

The documentation has this text :

> From Grails 1.2 onwards Webflow is no longer in Grails core, so you
>   must install the   Webflow plugin to use this feature: grails
>   install-plugin webflow

(see [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/single.html#webflow))

Just install the plugin and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Spelling finish correctly in

```
        }.to("finsh")
```

Might help

Comment: thats not the error! I even tried out running Grails in action example of chapter 9.. https://github.com/pledbrook/graina/tree/master/source-code/ch09/hubbub/grails-app/controllers/com/grailsinaction. This have ShopController as a webflow. Even this showing the same thing as my question...